# Set a column value to be null based on value from another column

Tags: mysql

I'm preparing a select query that should set a field as null if certain value is present in another field of the same query.

```
select statement_id, prod_id, description, exp_type, 
        curr_amt as Digital_income, curr_amt as Physical income 
from table1 
where date(created) = 'somedate'
```

Here, the field `exp_type` will have values like `"Digital", "Physical", "Download", "Stream"`.

I'm cloning `curr_amt` field as digital and physical. Most of the times both will have similar values only.

My requirement is if the `exp_type` is `"Physical"` I need the `curr_amt` as 'Digital_income'` to be null and visa versa.

Can anyone assist me in getting the desired output?

I tried using CASE, ISNULL and COALESCE but in vain

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF()`.

```
select statement_id, prod_id, description, exp_type, 
        IF(exp_type = 'Digital', curr_amt, NULL) as Digital_income, 
        IF(exp_type = 'Physical', curr_amt, NULL) as Physical_income 
from table1 
where date(created) = 'somedate'
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iEYSHEcNnqAArV5eLpnj/0)

Comment: It is making both of my columns (Digital_income & Physical_income) empty because "curr_amt" will have either 'Digital' or 'Physical' always and hence both of the columns are returning NULL.

Below is the kind of output I'm expecting

exp_type                   Digital Income                    Physical Income
Digital                        0.00709363                          NULL
Physical                      NULL                                 0.04552167

Comment: It shouldn't do that. If should return `curr_amt` when `exp_type` matches the `IF` condition.

Comment: I've added a link to a demo showing that it works.

Comment: Its weird to be not working for me. Let me try again

Comment: Maybe there are extra spaces or other characters in `exp_type`. Can you make a db-fiddle?